# Rotating a cube about its x axis

Tags: html, css, animation, rotation, cube

I am done designing a 3-D cube in pure html.
The cube is rotating fine about its y and z axis, but when I try to rotate it about its axis it behaves a little strange.
Instead of rotating about its new rotated x axis it just rotates about the original X axis.
You can see the code I've provided and suggest necessary amends.

Here is the CODE PEN link for you to tinker:

```
    &lt;a href="http://codepen.io/deviljinkazama/pen/KzoxEL"&gt;Link&lt;/a&gt;
```

Comment: I've worked with 3D things in CSS as well and it seems like that's just the way it works. It's weird, because when you rotate and then translate it (instead of rotating), it does translate over it's new axes.

Comment: Try to rotate it about the Z and Y axes and it will behave as expected but rotate it about X and it does not do what it's supposed to do.
Follow this method: in the animation keyframes part :-
Keep Z and Y rotation constant in the 0% and 100% part and put X=0deg in 0% part and put X=360deg in the 100% part.
Follow the same for the other axes when you want to rotate them specifically as well.